# Synchronizing S-Note notes between S4 and Note 10.1 2014

Tags: sync, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, s-note

Some time ago I used a pair of devices: **Samsung Galaxy S4** and **Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1**. I noticed, that they synchronized the notes in S Note nicely: even though S4 was unable to edit complex Note's notes, at least it was able to display them. And they were synchronized with my Samsung account as well.

I've replaced the 10.1 with the **Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 2014 edition**<sup>1</sup> lately and I've noticed, that it no longer synchronizes notes with my S4. Do you know maybe, why is it so? Is there a way to synchronize notes between my devices automatically?

---

<sup>1</sup> Samsung for sure sets the records in their devices name lengths...

Comment: What app are you talking about? S Note, or something else?

Comment: @DanHulme The default one, S Note.

Comment: Possibly silly question: have you signed into your Samsung account on the Note? Have you set it to synch? (I uninstalled S-Note on all my samsungs so I can't check the settings for you). There are some teious looking work arounds for this (seems to be an issue for everyone): http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-8-0/268797-s-note-not-syncing.html  May be more effort than it is worth. You could use Evernote or such and just export all your SNotes to it, and not have this again I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a similar issue trying to sync S Note's between a Galaxy Note 3 (smartphone) and a Galaxy Note 10.1 (as well as to a Galaxy Note 2).

The issue seems to be in the version of S Note running on Android 4.3.

On my Note 3, S Note saves the files as .spd files in a Snotedata folder.  On the Galaxy 10.1 the S Note documents are as .snb files in the "S Note" folder.

I think this explains why sync isn't working.